# Connecting boundary definitions

Tags: general-topology

I've noticed that there are several definitions of what a boundary of set is. However, I have problems with connecting them together.

If I say define the boundary as $\partial A = \bar{A} \backslash Int(A)$, then how do I transform this to $\partial A = \bar{A} \cap \overline{X \backslash A}$?

Comment: Show $\overline{A}\setminus A^\circ\subseteq\overline{A}\cap\overline{X\setminus A}$ and vice versa.

Comment: @Clayton I managed to prove it in one direction, but could you please give me any hint on how to prove $\bar{A} \cap \overline{X \backslash A} \subset \bar{A} \backslash Int(A)$?

Comment: @Angelika By the way, instead of `\backslash` you can use either `\setminus` or `\smallsetminus`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $2$ sets $X,Y$ it is true that $X\smallsetminus Y = X\cap Y^\complement$. It is sufficient to prove that: 
$$(A^\circ)^\complement  = \overline{\left(A^\complement\right)}.\tag 1$$

In order to prove $(1)$, we can follow the definitions.

**Proof:**

Let $x\in (A^\circ)^\complement \begin{array}[t]{l}\iff x\notin A^\circ \iff \forall \epsilon >0,\,\,  B(x,\epsilon)\not\subseteq Α\iff \forall \epsilon> 0,\,\, B(x,\epsilon)\cap A^\complement \neq \varnothing\\
\iff x \in \overline{\left(A^\complement\right)}.
\end{array}$

Comment: thanks a lot! I get it now

Comment: You are welcome!